Theming Angular material autocomplete options
How to modify the active and hover background-color of an option for Angular material component autocomplete?
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      @for (option of options; track option) {
        <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

How to apply a background-color (active, hover) for mat.option in theme.scss? For the full working example see StackBlitz.
:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  @include mat.option-color($theme???
}


I wasn't able to access your StackBlitz for some reason. Here's the documentation on applying themes to components: https://v17.material.angular.io/guide/theming#applying-a-theme-to-components

@ColemanTO StackBlitz link is that link from angular docs https://v17.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview#simple-autocomplete
